# How to augment one vector with antoher in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I have the following array

```
vector=array([[-0.16595599,  0.44064899, -0.99977125, -0.39533485, -0.70648822,
        -0.81532281]])
```

and I want to replace the first value for another, for example 0.

I am trying to generate an augmented vector like this and get an error:

```
np.column_stack([0],np.squeeze(vector)[1:-1])
*** TypeError: _column_stack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

or like this and also get an error

```
np.concatenate([0],np.squeeze(vector)[1:-1])
*** TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I don't know how to do it... In matlab this would be just [0, vector(2:end)]

I could just replace the first value with 0 but I need the original vector for other purposes.

Comment: Why not copy the array and then mutate on the copied numpy array? Eg. `b = a.copy()` then `b[0] = 0`.

Comment: Could you also provide what your desired output should look like?

Comment: @roshshetty, It has to be, output=array([0,  0.44064899, -0.99977125, -0.39533485, -0.70648822,
        -0.81532281]).   -swag2198 that is a solution, but i'm not sure is the best and more generalizable. That is how I'm solving it now.